# Making a RasPi backed Smart-TV

Tags: screen

I have been dreaming of building up my own smart home - and as a gamer, an integral part of that is to have a proper TV that can handle my media streaming needs and my DVB-C (cable TV) needs for when I want to watch some. However, I haven't found a TV yet I could also plug all my wanted devices into yet - which led me to a bit of an idea.

If I had a screen, managed to wire that up to a Raspberry Pi and ran something like Kodi on it... Would it be possible to create a Smart-TV backed by a Raspberry Pi?

Mainly, I need 5 HDMI inputs and 3 Composit inputs (all of them are gaming consoles) and would use the RasPi for the TV and media streaming. But even if I only had one HDMI and one Composit port and attached RF controlled switches to it, I could just add a RF sender and "switch inputs" by just controlling those switches. But, that is going a little too far, for now.

For now, is it possible to make your own Smart-TV with a screen, a RasPi and some soldering knowledge? The follow up would be, what would be a good method to add inputs to it so I could also connect my game consoles to it?

Answer (score 2):

A much more feasible solution would be to buy an actual, dumb TV and an HDMI splitter that can be controlled by with an IR blaster like this:
[image: HDMI Splitter]
For the composite inputs, you could get a similar IR composite blaster.

You could then get a Programmable IR Remote (controlling the splitter and the Pi) and Receiver module (getting the frequencies of the remote for the splitter(s) and receiving signals from your Programmable IR remote). You could connect the Raspberry Pi and your consoles to the HDMI inputs of your splitter(s) and install [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/) or [Libre Elec](https://libreelec.tv/) on the Pi.

In the end, you'll have an IR remote that uses most of the buttons to control the Pi, which has all of your smart TV features like the apps and internet connectivity, and 8 buttons for switching to any of the 8 gaming consoles.

If you really want to build an entire TV by yourself it wouldn't be that hard either. You could buy a large panel and do the exact same steps above.